# Spark Streaming - Maintaining state without updateStateByKey/mapWithState

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am trying to implement a Spark Streaming pipeline that is able to maintain state across batches without using updateStateByKey/mapWithState. I know the documentation states that those primitives are the recommended way, but I was tasked on finding an alternate solution.

The application needs to keep a cache composed of both data seen in every batch (from a Kinesis stream) as well as data retrieved from a Couchbase store.

I came with an implementation roughly described with the following pseudo-code:

Context:

```
 streamData <- data from Kinesis Stream
 cache <- Empty Dataset
 cacheEmpty <- true
 forEachRDD (streamData) {
    if (cacheEmpty) {
      cache <- warmupCache()
      cacheEmpty <- false
    }
    else {
      cache <- updateCache()
    }
    workingSet <- getWorkingSetFromCache(cache)
    output(workingSet)
 }
```

As you can see, I use forEachRDD (in the driver's process space) to update the cache Dataset, which is essentially updated with each batch. The cache is a Dataset variable that is declared outside the forEachRDD.

The problem I am having is that, although I am checkpointing the cache (to avoid the lineage to continuously grow), on every subsequent batch, the number of tasks executed by the Spark job are increasing, and it looks like Spark is tracking the state in the DAG to the first state of the cache variable (which starts Empty), so the time required to process every batch is increasing with each batch, and the pipeline eventually crashes because of a stack overflow exception.

Is there a way to avoid this behavior, or am I just pursuing a futile approach according to how Spark internally work?

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Thanks,
-Eduardo.